# Using sessions in classes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have code that's using session variables; it's both in the master page code behind and in the code behind of some aspx files. I wanted to put this code in a function that's in a different file but when I did that, the statement Session["VariableName"] became underlined in red on the word session. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Session` in a page is `System.Web.UI.Page.Session`. Since your page derives from the `Page` class, you can reference this with no qualification.

Your class probably does not derive from `Page`.

In  your class, use `HttpContext.Current.Session` instead.

---

Bryan brings up a good point. Your class code, in general, might not be getting called in the context of a request. Always check first:

```
if (HttpContext.Current != null)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
    {
        object cell = HttpContext.Current.Session["variable"];
        if (cell != null)
        {
            return (int) cell; // Or whatever
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, this.  Just make sure you have a valid HttpContext.Current first!  If you're creating a class library your code might not be called in a web app context.

Comment: If I initialize a session variable in there, will it be visible when  I get to the page. I want to initialize my session variable and run a query to fill 2 variables; all this in a class library.

Comment: @frenchie: yes. Session is Session. In fact, `System.Web.UI.Page.Session` is the same thing as `HttpContext.Current.Session`.